# Schedule Celery task to run after other task(s) complete

Tags: celery

I want to accomplish something like this:

```
results = []
for i in range(N):
    data = generate_data_slowly()
    res = tasks.process_data.apply_async(data)
    results.append(res)
celery.collect(results).then(tasks.combine_processed_data())
```

ie launch asynchronous tasks over a long period of time, then schedule a  dependent task that will only be executed once all earlier tasks are complete.

I've looked at things like `chain` and `chord`, but it seems like they only work if you can construct your task graph completely upfront.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interested, I ended up using this snippet:

```
@app.task(bind=True, max_retries=None)
def wait_for(self, task_id_or_ids):
    try:
        ready = app.AsyncResult(task_id_or_ids).ready()
    except TypeError:
        ready = all(app.AsyncResult(task_id).ready()
                    for task_id in task_id_or_ids)

    if not ready:
        self.retry(countdown=2**self.request.retries)
```

And writing the workflow something like this:

```
task_ids = []
for i in range(N):
    task = (generate_data_slowly.si(i) | 
            process_data.si(i)
            )
    task_id = task.delay().task_id
    task_ids.append(task_id)

final_task = (wait_for(task_ids) |
        combine_processed_data.si()
        )

final_task.delay()
```

Comment: Ehy great solution.. but I really don't like the 2**self.request.retries as it can literally explodes easily: that's better to use a static value. Further, there's a typo in the code: `final_task = (wait_for(task_ids) | combine_processed_data.si())` should be `final_task = (wait_for(task_ids).si() | combine_processed_data.si())`

Answer (score 1):

That way you would be running your tasks synchronously.

The solution depends entirely on how and where `data` are collected. Roughly, given that `generate_data_slowly` and `tasks.process_data` are synchronized, a better approach would be to join both in one `task` (or a `chain`) and to `group` them.

`chord` will allow you to add a callback to that `group`.

The simplest example would be:

```
from celery import chord

@app.task
def getnprocess_data():
    data = generate_data_slowly()
    return whatever_process_data_does(data)

header = [getnprocess_data.s() for i in range(N)]
callback = combine_processed_data.s()

chord(header)(callback).get()
```

Comment: no, I don't want `generate_data_slowly` and `process_data` to be synchronized. `process_data` should execute by a worker while another set of data is being generated. `generate_data_slowly` involves hardware and must run in a master process, not shuffle between workers.